# Python How to loop only selected keys and their value in a dictionary

Tags: python

How to iterate only selected key in a python dictionary?

```
    for k, v in myDict:
        print ('key = {}'.format(k))
        print ("value = {}".format(v))
```

This will print out all keys and its values. 
Lets say I only want key1, key2 and key5, and their values, any idea?

Thank you

Comment: Then you should use if statement in the loop to check for that, there is no such thing as "looping over some part of the collection" unless you use filter.

Comment: @Ali Well… `for k, v in (i for i in myDict.items() if i[0] in ('key1', ...)):`

Comment: @deceze so O(n^2) is better than O(log(n)) you say? :) Even though your answer looks like a one liner very clean looking code, in reality it is just slower than checking the condition with if in a loop.

Comment: @Ali It's not `O(n^2)`, it's a generator expression…

Comment: New day new information for me then sir ;) well played

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a simple `if statement`.

Note : don't forget `.items()` to iterate over keys + values in a dictionary

```
myDict = {
    "key1": 3,
    "key2": 2,
    "key3": 5,
    "key4": 8,
    "key5": 1,
    "key6": 4
}
desired_keys = ["key1", "key2", "key5"]
for k, v in myDict.items():
    if k in desired_keys:
        print ('key = {}'.format(k))
        print ("value = {}".format(v))
```

Output :

```
key = key1
value = 3
key = key2
value = 2
key = key5
value = 1
```